# Ubuntu complains that I am not "Owner" when copying files to certain folders

Tags: 14.04, permissions, themes, users, directory

I am trying to copy a folder into the `user/share/themes` folder on Ubuntu 14.04, and it's telling me I cannot do this because I am not "owner". So I right-clicked the `usr/share/themes` folder > `Properties` > `Permissions` tab and tried to change the permissions but they're all greyed-out/disabled.

So then I opened up Terminal, entered `groupmod TAB TAB TAB` > `sudo adduser jase root` to try and get higher permissions or something - and it worked. I verified that I added myself as root by `id jase`. But that still didn't fix the problem. I still can't copy folders or files to `usr/share/themes` folder.

How can I do this? How do I become "owner"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy the file using sudo

```
sudo cp file destination
```

For directories use th -R flag

```
sudo cp -R directory destination
```

If the files or directories have spaces, you have to quote or escape ( \ ) them

```
sudo cp "file with spaces" destination
sudo cp file\ with\ spaces destination
```

For information on Linux permissions and the use of sudo, see:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

and

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: I just tried that. With: jase@Jase-PC:~$ sudo cp '/home/jase/Downloads/flattastic_13_01_2014_by_nale12-d70zd5z' '/usr/share/themes'
[sudo] password for jase:
cp: omitting directory ‘/home/jase/Downloads/flattastic_13_01_2014_by_nale12-d70zd5z’
 but then it didn't work. It said: "that it omitted something."

Comment: I'm sorry but the link above - none of that stuff works. I've tried it a dozen times. And I'm not that new to linux (I've just been away from Linux for a while). Anyway, I've managed to solve it by entering `sudo chown -R jase /usr/share/themes` into terminal. I remember doing that last year. It's working just fine now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That is not really a good idea (changing ownership and permissions of system files). You need the -R flag with cp for directories . `cp -R directory destination`. The error messages in Linux are (usually) helpful, if you do not understand them, post the command and error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy directories with cp in linux, unfortunately. The other answer is correct that you need root privledges with `sudo`, but you should do something like this to copy a directory:
`cd /home/jase/Downloads`
`tar cvf flattastic.tar flattastic/`
`sudo mv flattastic.tar /usr/share/themes/`
`cd /usr/share/themes`
`sudo tar xvf flattastic.tar`
`sudo rm flattastic.tar`

BUT, in your specific case, there's something else you can do, I think.

Try
`cd ~`
`mkdir .themes`
`mv /home/jase/Downloads/flattastic/ ~/.themes/flattastic`
You might have to log out and back in, but I think that this would let you add themes without using sudo or root privledges at all.

Comment: That is not true, use the -R flag for directories. `cp -R /home/jase/Downloads/flattastic /usr/share/themes/`