# Copy a file from one ext4 partition to other

Tags: filesystem, ext4

I have two ext4 partition and I want to copy some files from one partition to other in GUI not using terminal, but it does not allow me to do so. It simply a root permission problem.

I just want to know that is there any way to copy a file from one Ext4 partition to other without using terminal?

Comment: In general, you have to either change ownership / permissions of the destination (requires root) or copy the files as root. Depending on what you are copying where, the terminal is just as easy. `sudo cp file /destination`. Alternately run nautilus as root. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/11760/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-nautilus-and-sudo-nautilus

Comment: Yah copying from terminal is easy. In my case I am installing a wordpress plugin from browser and it goes to /var/www/html directory. I have tried options like changing the ownership and permission of the destination folder and it still can't able to create a directory over there. But I haven't tried nautilus yet.

Comment: Thanks nautilus is the answer of my question. I want to know that because I was facing problem to installing wordpress plugin from browser into a directory /var/www/html it always say that 'Couldn't create directory'. So I was thinking that if I am able to create directory or copy files into a Ext4 partition in the form of GUI then I could solve my above problem. But I don't think 'nautilus' work for this. I know it is a separate issue. By the way thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the quesion ...

> I just want to know that is there any way to copy a file from one Ext4 partition to other without using terminal?

You can use Nautilus if you copy the file over with the user name that owns the destination you want to copy the file to. That user needs to own that location or needs to be part of a group owning that location.

---

If you want any user to be able to do that: no, not without changing. It would be a security problem if you could. This will at least require you to one time change the ownership of the destination and doing that with a terminal would be the easiest. And the only user that can do this needs to be an admin of your system (someone that can use "sudo").

---

Some links to help you out (but they will rely on the terminal):

- [Change owner of internal hard drive partition from root to user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43570/change-owner-of-internal-hard-drive-partition-from-root-to-user)
- https://askubuntu.com/a/493831/15811

In case you have questions regarding terminal commands: feel free to drop into [AskUbuntu Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) (20 reputation required). There will always be someone there willing to help.